# How to retrieve parent child relationship data using entity framework and do pagination/filtering/sorting on it

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I have one DB table which is self-referenced to form the parent child relationship.

| Id | Name | ParentId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | null |
| 2 | B | 1 |
| 3 | C | 2 |
| 4 | D | 2 |
| 5 | E | 1 |

I want this table be queried thru EF core and retrieve the data in the below format

```
{
  Id: 1,
  Name: A,
  Children: {
    {
      Id: 2,
      Name : B,
      Children :{
        {
           Id: 3,
           Name : C,
           Children :null
        },
        {
           Id: 4,
           Name : D,
           Children :null
        },
      } 
    },
    {
      Id: 5,
      Name: C,
      Children :null 
    },
  },
}
```

My Model class is

```
class Temp
{
   public int Id {get; set }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public Temp Parent { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Temp> children { get; set; } // Navigation property
}
```

If I do a query like this

```
dbContext.Temp.Include(x => x.Children);
```

Then this brings all the data with Children, also the children are listed under the main list as well, although if any item has parent then it should not come in the main list rather it should come under its parent's children array.

the result is like

- A

  - B

    - C
    - D
  - E
- B
- C
- D
- E

Many thanks

Comment: With EF it is only possible if you specify a lot of includes: `dbContext.Temp.Include(x => x.Children).ThenInclude(x => x.Children).ThenInclude(x => x.Children).ThenInclude(x => x.Children);`

Answer (score 1):

It's a common problem - and not something EFCore handles natively.

> **Point of caution** - you almost certainly want to add checking to insure
> all new /edited records don't inadvertently create circular
> references, eg: `Temp1 = new Temp {Id = 1, ParentId = 2}; Temp2 = new Temp {Id = 2, ParentId = 1};` - this'll cause bad things to happen when loading a tree....

First, the not-so-obvious obvious solution, use lazy-loading after only retrieving the root nodes:

```
// Get a list of root nodes.
// Optionally, add pagination, filtering and sorting to the query - .Where(x => x.Name.Contains("blah")).Skip(10).Take(5).OrderBy(x => x.Sequence) etc.
var rootNodes = dbContext.Temp.Where(x => x.parentId == null).ToList();

// Child nodes will be loaded as you access them.
foreach (var node in rootNodes)
{
    foreach (var child in node.Children) {
        // Do something with children that were lazy-loaded.
    }
}
```

For more info on configuring Lazy-Loading: https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2019/01/30/lazyloading/

> Note: Lazy Loading CAN lead to inefficient behavior / unexpected DB
> queries. It's convenient, but convenience comes at a price...

If your business rules dictate a maximum depth, you can use include statements as follows, notice the filter to only retrieve root nodes:

```
// For a maximum depth of two (or root, leaf, leaf)
// Optionally, add pagination, filtering and sorting to the query - .Where(x => x.Name.Contains("blah")).Skip(10).Take(5).OrderBy(x => x.Sequence) etc.
var query = dbContext.Temp
    .Where(x => x.ParentId == null)
    .Include(x => x.children)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.children);
```

For trees of unknown depth, you'll best be served by getting the entire flat list and building the nesting yourself (client side instead of EF Query), note that pagination will have to be on the result:

```
// My recursive function to load child nodes.
Action<List<Temp>, <Temp>> LoadChildren = delegate(sourceList, loadChildrenFor) {
    // Get the children for the specified node.
    loadChildrenFor.Children = sourceList.Where(x => x.ParentId == loadChildrenFor.Id).ToList();
    // Remove the children from the source list AND load its children.
    foreach(var node in loadChildrenFor.Children)
    {
        sourceList.Remove(node); // Don't need in source list any more, it's a child.
        LoadChildren(sourceList, node);
    }
}

var allNodes = dbContext.Temp.ToList();
foreach (var node in allNodes.Where(x => x.parentId == null))
    LoadChildren(allNodes, node);

// Now allNodes ONLY contains root nodes with all their children populated, // Optionally, add pagination, filtering and sorting to the query - .Where(x => x.Name.Contains("blah")).Skip(10).Take(5).OrderBy(x => x.Sequence) etc.
```

For a generic implementation of list flattening: https://habr.com/en/post/516596/

If the tree is very large and is of unknown depth, and you only need a subset (or one branch) multiple queries inside a recursive function would be most appropriate:

```
// My recursive function to load child nodes.
Action<Temp> LoadChildren = delegate(ofNode) {
    ofNode.Children = dbContext.Temp.Where(x => x.ParentId == ofNode.Id).ToList();
    foreach(var node in ofNode.Children)
        LoadChildren(node);
}

// A list of root nodes I'm interested in - could be any depth in tree.
// Optionally, add pagination and sorting to the query - .Skip(10).Take(5).OrderBy(x => x.Sequence) etc.
var rootNodesImInterestedIn = dbContext.Temp.Where(x => x.Id == 5).ToList();
// Load the children for each root node I'm interested in.
foreach(var node in rootNodesImInterestedIn)
    LoadChildren(node);
```

Comment: Actually best solution here is Recursive CTE. Anyway if someone likes killing database, this may work.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, Yes, if your database supports it, but even then, the recursive CTE would still return a FLAT table of items that you'll need to convert into an object hierarchy.  Also, this post is about using EntityFramework, a ORM tool for .NET development, not about MS SQL Server (one of many possible underlying database providers Entity Framework may be using.).

Comment: Almost all mainstream databases supports that (I've got your point). Usually if this data needed only for display - better to do post processing on the client side. I have improved several projects which are used lazy loading or Includes for such task - it kills database. And usually it is core functionality, like permissions, assets, etc.

Comment: Also notice that there are 4 distinct solutions - only the first uses lazy loading (which I would NOT recommend, LOL). I would prefer the remaining solutions personally, depending on size of table, whether you need just a subset, etc. Then of course, there's caching opportunities for rarely changed data. All of that seemed outside the question however.

Comment: No problem ;) EF gives me a job when developers puts their hands down. But sometimes it is not easy to understand why they used such techniques ;)

Comment: Thanks! Just getting started on here - hope I am doing things right... Long time ago was active on ExpertsExchange until they changed business models.

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<Category> toHierarchical(List<Category> categories)
{
    foreach (var category in categories.ToList())
    {
        var childs = categories.Where(s => s.ParentId == category.Id).ToList();
        category.Childs = childs;
        categories.RemoveAll(childs.Contains);
    }
    return categories;
}
```

Enjoy the benefits of `reference type`. So simple right? :)

**UPDATE**:
You can also use this;

```
var result = await _categoryReadRepository.GetIncluded(
        d => d.Include(r => r.Childs)
    ).ToListAsync(); // <-- actually I get all data with childs here, you can use your own method
var response = result.Where(r=>r.ParentId == null);
```